# How to Install SQL Server 2016 Instance beside Existing 2008 r2 Instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I Want to install MSSQL Server 2016 and I have MSSQL Server 2008 r2 as my current instance. During setup when I want to select the features there is no SQL Engine in the feature list. Beside I do not want to upgrade my current version.

Any Experience/Idea?

Comment: What is the complete file name of the installer you're using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.SQL.Server.2016.Enterprise.x64.Iso > setup.exe

Comment: how did you fix this?